# How to write assertions

Tags: debugging, elisp

How does one write assertions in Emacs Lisp?  I know that `cl-macs.el` has `cl-assert` and `cl-check-type`, but I'm wondering if there's a native Emacs way to perform something that basic.

Comment: `cl-lib` is written in Emacs Lisp, how is that not "native"?

Comment: `cl-lib` is a Common Lisp compatibility library.  In many areas, elisp has features that are better or simply different from their Common Lisp counterparts (gv comes to mind).

Comment: There isn't.  Don't expect something to exist, just because you think it should.  Emacs Lisp is pretty minimal after all, so you're much better off either writing it yourself or finding something already written for you.

Comment: Besides, `assert` is not really a “basic” thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked through the Lisp code bundled with Emacs, and I've found that:

- most files use `cl-assert` after doing `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl-lib))`;
- some files use `assert` after doing `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))`;
- there are a small number of specialised assertion macros in the Emacs library, notably `check-face` and `check-coding-system`, but they don't seem to be used much;
- only a very few packages define their own specialised assertion macros, e.g. `ibuffer-assert-ibuffer-mode` or `tramp-check-proper-method-and-host`.

One thing that wasn't obvious to me is that `cl-assert` only requires `cl-lib` at compile time — in Emacs 25 it expands into a call to `cl--assertion-failed` which is preloaded, while in Emacs 24 it expands into calls to `error` and `signal`.

My conclusion is therefore that one should depend on `cl-lib` at compile time and use `cl-assert`, or write specialised macros that expand into `cl-assert`.

Comment: A note for readers on older Emacs: `cl--assertion-failed` (and `cl-preloaded.el`) are new in Emacs 25.

Comment: Right, added more information.

Comment: Typing `C-h` `f` `assert` `RET` => `assert` is an alias for `cl-assert` in "cl.el".
  This function is obsolete since 27.1;
  use `cl-assert` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an assert macro in elisp based on an expert's advice on emacs mailing list:

```
(defmacro assert (test-form)
  `(when (not ,test-form)
     (error "Assertion failed: %s" (format "%s" ',test-form))))

(assert (equal t nil))
```

Comment: How is that more useful than `cl-assert`?

Comment: You didn't ask for more useful. You asked "how does one write.." Rephrase your question.